# How to avoid the "ambiguous" error message when using joins to create several tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use the following code to create a list of customers and their brands that they buy. The `brands` table has the brand name and `customer_id` is in the `customers` table. To link them I have to get the `brand_id` and `receipt_id` linked together via the `receipts` table (connects to `customers` table) and `receipt_item_details1` table (connects to `brands` table).

So, `receipt_item_details1` table (has `brand_id` column to then connect to `brands` table) and new table `customer_receipts` (created by first inner most subquery) are trying it to be linked by `receipt_id`. I'd like to show the `customer_id` column when I build my table joining these two table (an original: `receipt_item_details1` joined to a new table: `customer_receipts`).

ISSUE: I keep getting the following error. how do Infix it and also list the brands?

> "column reference "customer_id" is ambiguous
>   LINE 3: ...pts.receipt_id, receipt_item_details1.receipt_id, customer_r.."

```
SELECT customer_brandids.brand_id, brands.brand_id, customer_brandids.customer_id, brands.brand_name
    FROM 
        (SELECT customer_receipts.receipt_id, receipt_item_details1.receipt_id, customer_receipts.customer_id, receipt_item_details1.brand_id
        FROM
            (SELECT receipts.customer_id, customers.customer_id, receipts.receipt_id
            FROM receipts
            INNER JOIN customers
            ON receipts.customer_id = customers.customer_id) AS customer_receipts
        INNER JOIN receipt_item_details1
        ON customer_receipts.receipt_id = receipt_item_details1.receipt_id) AS customer_brandids
    INNER JOIN brands
    ON customer_brandids.brand_id = brands.brand_id
```

Comment: Hi, in your other question you already accepted and upvoted. That's great! Please do this in this one as well. That shows that your problem is solved and gives something back (reputation, scoring points) to those who took time to deal with your problem :)

Answer (score 4):

Your inner subselect

```
 (SELECT receipts.customer_id, customers.customer_id
```

generates a result with two columns named `customer_id`. So your next higher subselect cannot differ between both columns if you reference `customer_id`

You should give one or both an alias:

```
 (SELECT receipts.customer_id as r_customer_id, 
      customers.customer_id as c_customer_id
```

Then your next higher query can call

```
 SELECT customer_receipts.c_customer_id...
```

So first step of solving the problem:

```
SELECT 
    customer_brandids.brand_id,                       
    brands.brand_id, 
    customer_brandids.c_customer_id,                    --> reference alias
    brands.brand_name
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         customer_receipts.receipt_id as c_receipt_id,  --> same problem
         receipt_item_details1.receipt_id as r_receipt_id,
         customer_receipts.c_customer_id,               --> reference alias
         receipt_item_details1.brand_id
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             receipts.customer_id as r_customer_id,     --> here was the problem
             customers.customer_id as c_customer_id, 
             receipts.receipt_id
        FROM receipts
        INNER JOIN customers
        ON receipts.customer_id = customers.customer_id) AS customer_receipts
    INNER JOIN receipt_item_details1
    ON customer_receipts.receipt_id = receipt_item_details1.receipt_id) AS customer_brandids
INNER JOIN brands
ON customer_brandids.brand_id = brands.brand_id
```

---

**Addionally**:

1. You don't need to take both columns (e.g. of `receipt_id`) because of the `INNER JOIN` it is ensured that both columns have the same value
2. You can use aliases to shorten your query.
3. You don't need to create a subquery for each join. Just join.

All in all, this should do the same:

```
SELECT b.brand_id, c.customer_id, b.brand_name 
FROM receipts r
INNER JOIN customers c ON r.customer_id = c.customer_id
INNER JOIN receipt_item_details1 rid ON r.receipt_id = rid.receipt_id
INNER JOIN brands b ON b.brand_id = rid.receipt_id
```

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7003dd01701e39f40271ae5dd0b4443f)

Comment: Thanks so much, curious as to why this show the coulumns but not the data

Comment: You mean the fiddle? Because I don't know your data. How should I build a table with your data? The fiddle conatins only empty columns, created to show that the query works without any errors. The tables are reverse engineered by you query :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use nested selects when it is not necessary, try to use joins, and query will be more simple and will look something like this

```
select * from receipts
join customers on receipts.customer_id = customers.customer_id
join receipt_item_details1 on receipts.receipt_id = receipt_item_details1.receipt_id
join brands on receipt_item_details1.brand_id = brands.brand_id
```

Instead of asterisk you can define columns you want to get

Comment: This is great for me to see all the columns. Thakn you.  I'm not seeing rows dsiplayed though. is there an error with the way I joined them?

Comment: Join will exclude rows, that do not have associated rows in other tables. Try to use ‘left join’ instead of ‘join’